# 41 working days no decision made yet by UKVI for visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I had my biometric on the 24th of october 2018 from New york, 
My wife and daughter in Nigeria had theirs on 1st of November.
they both got their visas on the 13th of November and have since gotten their visas.

I applied with the hope of spending christmas with them, be it in the UK or Nigeria.
From the 24th of october that i mailed it in, no decision made on mine yet, I took 2 weeks off from work from the 21st of december to january 5th which begins tomorrow

I contacted them after 15 working days, only to have it excalated to another queue that takes another 15 working days, at the end this long wait.

i got an email saying they will prioritize it now and they should reach a decision in 5-7 working days. today make it another 10 working days.

I am seriously weighing asking for my passport so i can atleast travel to Nigeria but learnt i may be in for another 15 working days wait to have it returned except i expedite the cancellation which is pay excess fees just to cancel.

The agents on the paid phone service or email is only able to tell you the status. Any suggestion on what other options i have not explored, is there an office one can reach, how long does a passport return actually take without paying to have my passport

Today makes it 41 working days for a visit visa from when i mailed in my passport and i have my passport trapped and i can't even travel out of the US.

Is there a process to reach a supervisor at UKVI to see why my application is delayed, the phone operators are not equiped to do anything.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but what is your question?

Comment: Is there a process to reach a supervisor at UKVI to see why my application is delayed, the phone operators are not equiped to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are wanting to contact them in English there is a [GOV Form](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english) specifically for ***Contact UK Visas and Immigration about your application***, when putting your information in it shows these results:

> **Contact UK Visas and Immigration in English**
>
> You can call or email English-speaking staff with a question about your application. Contact centre staff cannot give you advice about your personal circumstances.
>
> > **By phone**
> >
> > Telephone: 00 44 203 481 1736
> >
> > Monday to Friday, 24 hours
> >
> > Calls cost £1.37 per minute on top of your standard network charges.
> >
> > **By email**
> >
> > [Email UK Visas and Immigration.](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English)
> >
> > Emails enquiries cost £5.48. You will not be charged for any follow-up emails about the same enquiry.

You are paying for the service so I'm sure they will try and answer your questions and hopefully get a better response than contacting UKVI. You are also not asking for advice as you just want to check the status of your application.